# DailyMotion Upload API missing file error

Tags: dailymotion-api

I am trying to upload an mp4 video to the DailyMotion Upload API. When I send the file content, I receive an error response as below.

```
Id = 31, Status = RanToCompletion, Method = "{null}", 
Result = "{\"error\":\"missing file\",\"seal\":\"4a24a4c8a51771d9d3b8bcd4462e721b\"}"
```

I am using C# in .net 4.5 and have generated the following calls:

```
POST [[UPLOAD URL]] HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="c83ccd81-39f7-4167-a8f1-74ab63eb4219"
Host: upload-01.sv6.dailymotion.com
Content-Length: 9893501
Expect: 100-continue

--c83ccd81-39f7-4167-a8f1-74ab63eb4219
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="TESTFILE.mp4"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

[[[FILE BINARY]]]
```

I have successfully uploaded using DailyMotion's CURL sample. Using Fiddler, CURL generates the following:

```
POST [[UPLOAD URL]] HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.33.0
Host: upload-02.sv6.dailymotion.com
Accept: */*
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 9893509
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------a49610ec11411f2a

--------------------------a49610ec11411f2a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="TESTFILE.mp4"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

[[FILE BINARY]]
```

The file binary looks good and the only differences I see are the connection and User-Agent headers. Researching the Connection header, it looks like Keep-Alive is unnecessary with HTTP/1.1. I have tried several different User-Agents (Mozilla, CURL, IE) but no change in response.

I appreciate any insight into what is happening. 
Thank you!

EDIT Added code:

```
mediatype = "video/mp4"
name = "file"
filename = "file"
data = {byte[9893291]}

 public async Task UploadRequest(string mediatype, string name, string filename, byte[] data)
    {
        using(HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));

            var videoContent = new ByteArrayContent(data);
            videoContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data");
            videoContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name = "\"file\"";
            videoContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = filename;
            videoContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream");

            requestContent.Add(videoContent, name);

            Apirequest.HttpRequestMessage.Content = requestContent;

            Apirequest.HttpResponseMessage = httpClient.SendAsync(Apirequest.HttpRequestMessage).Result;
            Apirequest.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        }
    }
```

EDIT Updated following help

```
POST http://upload-02.nyc.dailymotion.com/upload?uuid=c8542d0a9be73c55fbace1ee4aa1744b&seal=4770461f7f07b4e0c15750d70bc44377 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=62fcae82-e1b2-4df3-99c4-90fad29be62d
Host: upload-02.nyc.dailymotion.com
Content-Length: 9893493
Expect: 100-continue

--62fcae82-e1b2-4df3-99c4-90fad29be62d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Testfile.mp4"; filename=Testfile.mp4
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

���ftypmp42���mp41mp42isom���wide���mdat!�@h!
�Ќ>��SZa��x�M�޹SZa��{�!
�ˊ��]C���I��x�8V]�F}=�_Pc1�w�d>��.�!
������hRDq��0�`D�4�QG��A��nn��û�6��ݳ���ι�τpE����s���8)�=����^�ʇ�/�N8k.��]Jr)�z���pTR�
=}.�!
[[FILE GOES ON]]
ðb ’h  'v† )ˆI 7| F3• Ršv _Ê0 kC yDÀ ‚¡] ‰¢ h ŽÂi /
×ÿ  ¥ Ó
‘`Q ‘É ’Ö ’K ’Õ ’ÿ\ “ˆŠ “³Â ”"G ”7»   +udta   #titl    ÇTestFile 
--62fcae82-e1b2-4df3-99c4-90fad29be62d--
```

EDIT: A code example of the fix was requested. It is as follows:

```
videoContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "\"" + name + "\"";
```

Comment: can you provide the actual code ? it may help to understand what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigation, it looks like the *nginx-upload-module* that is responsible for handling file uploads on our side doesn't understand quoted content boundaries in HTTP headers, which, [according to the RFC1341](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html#z0), is not the standard way of defining boundaries in HTTP anyway. It looks like the C# library you are using to craft your request may be following the standard for the `multipart/digest` content type instead of the `multipart/form-data` (cf section 7.2.4). Please check whether this is something you have any control on or not and test again.

Comment: I was able to do a workaround to remove the quotes from the boundary. I am getting the same error still. I may have multiple errors, but I cannot see the details. Thank you!

Comment: Can you join the full HTTP request you are trying to execute without obfuscating the upload URL and including a few bytes from the file itself + the boundaries? Your problem doesn't ring a bell here, I suspect there might indeed be another error with something else than the upload process itself. Are you absolutely sure you're correctly authenticating the user?

Comment: Updated the code and posted result. I checked that I am authenticated, can get upload ticket/upload URL. I also confirmed that I can do other activities authenticated.

Comment: This is going to sound stupid but, you're now missing some quotes :) At the beginning, you had quotes around the file name in the Content-Disposition header (cf section 19.5.1 of the [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html)), now you don't have them. Just add them back and report back! It is causing errors on our side when we test without quotes.

Comment: That did it. The boundary cannot have quotes and the filename does. Thank you!

Comment: Great, happy that we could help you. If you have any problem in the future, don't hesitate to use Stack Overflow again, we check here regularly.

Comment: @ScoobySnax can you post your code for working around the quotes? Everything I try results in 'Improper Header Use'